# Should a decorator class be abstract in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I've been reading about the decorator pattern. It make sense to me that a decorator class is abstract since I can't see why it should instantiated by it self in any scenario, however I actually haven't found any place that states it has to be abstract no matter what.

Is it correct that it is always abstract?

Comment: Semantics of decorators vary by language, so you should indicate the language which you're asking about.

Comment: I'm not sure how an abstract decorator would be useful. You need a concrete decorator class in order to be able to create one. Otherwise, how could you ever decorate anything? Whether the decorator extends an abstract class or not is an implementation detail that doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it in a wrong way. I mean the decorator itself. Should it be instantiated as an abstract class?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_example_(coffee_making_scenario) for an example. There are two decorators: WithMilk and WithSprinkles. They're both concrete classes. If they were abstract classes, they would be unusable. I have no idea of what you mean by "instantiated as an abstract class". Give a concrete example to explain what you mean.

Comment: In your link the WindowDecorator is Abstract. My question is, does it always need to be abstract?

Comment: Since you can't instantiate an abstract class, your question "Should it be instantiated as an abstract class?" is completely without meaning. Are you asking if you should program to an interface?

Comment: In my link, WindowDecorator is an abstract base class for the two concrete decorators HorizontalScrollbarDecorator and VerticalScrollbarDecorator. And as I saif in my previous comment, that's an implementation detail: whether or not those two concrete decorators extend an abstract class doesn't change anything to what they do, and to how you use them.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, decorator does not have to be abstract.

In the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_example_(coffee_making_scenario)) there are 2 types of functionality implemented:

- Delegating to the instance that needs to be decorated
- Modifying the functionality of the decorated object

In the Wikipedia example the classes have only 2 methods. That's why it is not obvious if moving delegating functionality to a separate class makes any sense at all. The logic of CoffeeDecorator could have been implemented directly in the classes WithMilk  and WithSprinkles. But if you want to decorate a class that has 20-30 methods, then it makes sense to design classes like on this Wikipedia page: You put the pure delegating logic to one class and the logic specific for particular decorator to its subclass. Think of *separation of concerns*.

With such design it is easier to test and to maintain the code. Testing of the base decorator class is easy, because each of its methods should do exactly the same as the method of the decorated object. And testing of the particular decorator means "just" testing of a (usually) few overridden methods. When you are analyzing a bug or you want to extend the decorator, you know well the responsibility of each class.

Must the base decorator be abstract? No, but this can be useful. In case you make the base decorator class non abstract, every developer will be able to create an instance of it. But this base class has no additional business functionality compared to the decorated class, where as it means some performance overhead. To avoid unneeded performance overhead, it makes sense to declare this class as abstract.